# in -init method won't change subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, superclass

I have a object derived from UIView, it is AIItem, this item have UIImageView *status_view, now I need another object AIAnotherItem derived from AIItem, problem is in status_view.

For Example :

AIItem init method

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    status_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
    status_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"item_image.png"];
    [self addSubview:status_view];
}
```

}

AIAnotherItem init method

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
self = [super initWithName:name];
if (self) {
   status_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_item_image.png"];
}
return self;
}
```

in AIAnotherItem I set another image to status_view but it won't changed.
Question is why ? and how do this ?

Comment: How do you reference the image from the nib? Second is why do you have [super init] in AllItem and initWithName in AlAnotherItem

Comment: AIItem derived from UIView, but I need for it another init method for example initWithName: P.S. I didn't use nib files

Comment: The problem is though you load it status_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_item_image.png"];, you don't add it. You need to add it again

Comment: status_view is present but with first image item_image.png but i need to set for it another_item_image.png

Comment: Sorry forget everything I said. Can you put a breakpoint in status_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"another_item_image.png"];
in this line and check it runs

Comment: it runs normal, I create a folder in AIAnotherItem init, and it created, but to modify subview I can't :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17833/discussion-between-igor-bidiniuc-and-s-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless what the mechanics are of this not working (I am sure you will figure it out), I believe that you are perhaps not going about this the right way.

Would it not be more logical to have class `AIItem.h` that has an empty property `statusView`? And then two derived classes (or instances of the same subclass) that inherit the same `statusView` but fill it with different images?

I think this would correspond more closely to the philosophy behind *[inheritance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW12)*.

Comment: thanks for answer, but this work very good, problem was in thread, I didn't set image in second class on mainThread :)